# ¿Como puedo entender este codigo?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estuvo casi una hora en entender este codigo

```
      def suma1():
          numero = 3
          suma = 5
          while numero <= 10:   
              suma = numero + suma
              numero = numero + 1 
          return f"La suma es {suma}"

      def suma9():
          numero = 9
          suma = 5
          while numero <= 10:   
              suma = numero + suma
              numero = numero + 1
          return f"La suma es {suma}"

      print(suma1())
      print(suma9())

      La suma es 60
      La suma es 24
```

¿Por que en la primera función me devuelve un resultado mayor que la segunda función, si la varible **numero** en la segd funcion tiene un valor mas alto que en la primera funcion?

Comment: Por que la primera función se repitira más veces, esto dado que la variable ```numero``` es menor que en la segunda función cuyo valor es ```9``` y este proceso solo se repitira dos veces

Comment: Porque en la segunda, a pesar de que el número es mayor, el bucle while solamente se ejecuta dos veces (para número=9 y número=10) y en la otra unas cuantas veces más.

Comment: MUchas gracias, se entendio todo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te devuelve un valor mayor, dado que itera una mayor cantidad de veces. Cuando tienes dudas de este tipo, es útil realizar la ejecución del programa paso a paso, ya sea con la ayuda de un depurador, o bien en papel o mentalmente.

Manualmente, puedes hacer una tabla donde llevas el control del valor de las variables, a medida que se va ejecutando el código. Aunque el ciclo no lleva (ni necesita) un contador de las iteraciones, yo usualmente lo agrego, porque me ayuda a repasarlo mentalmente, así que mi tabla tiene una primera columna con el número de cada iteración.

El ejercicio, para la primera función, sería algo como:

| Iteración | suma | numero |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Inicialización | 5 | 3 |
| 1 | 8 | 4 |
| 2 | 12 | 5 |
| 3 | 17 | 6 |
| 4 | 23 | 7 |
| 5 | 30 | 8 |
| 6 | 38 | 9 |
| 7 | 47 | 10 |
| 8 | 57 | 11 |

Como puedes observar, al entrar a cada iteración, en la fila superior tengo los valores de las variables y durante la iteración voy anotando los nuevos valores, de manera que en esta fila tengo las variables tal como terminan esa iteración del ciclo, lo que me permite evaluar la condición del `while` y determinar si hay una iteración más o no.

En este caso particular he parado cuando ya no se cumple la condición `numero <= 10'.

Veamos ahora la segunda función:

| Iteración | suma | numero |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Inicialización | 5 | 9 |
| 1 | 14 | 10 |
| 2 | 24 | 11 |

La salida correcta para el programa no es la que has publicado (quizás cambiaste algo a última ahora en el código, sino que es esta:

```
La suma es 57
La suma es 24
```

Creo que queda claro ahora por que devuelve dichos valores.

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS HERMANO, BUENA EXPLICACIÓN.

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda. Considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada, pues esto ayudará en el futuro a quienes lleguen aquí a identificar que la respuesta **si** fue de ayuda. Recuerda que en StackOverflow puedes saber, de esta manera, si hubo una respuesta útil y cuál es. Es muy útil cuando llegas aquí googlando un proximo problema. Esto no resta mérito a otras respuestas y en ocasiones habrá buenas o hasta mejores respuestas no aceptadas, pero si que ayuda. Si no sabes como aceptar una respuesta, haz el [tour].

Comment: Entendido, no me había fijado. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Un gusto ser de ayuda. :)